# Creating Custom Operators in RxJava2?

Tags: rx-java2

I'm having trouble finding an example of how to make a custom operator with RxJava 2. I've considered a few approaches:

1. Using `Observable.create`, and then `flatMap`ing on it from the source observable. I can get this working, but it doesn't quite feel right. I end up creating a static function which I provide the source `Observable`, and then flatMap on the source. In the OnSubscribe, I  then instantiate an object that I pass the emitter to, which handles and manages the Observable / Emitter (as it's not trivial, and I want everything as encapsulated as possible).
2. Creating an `ObservableOperator` and providing it to `Observable.lift`. I can't find any examples of this for RxJava 2. I had to debug into my own example to make sure my understanding of upstream and downstream were correct. Because I can't find any examples or documentation on this for RxJava 2 I'm a little worried I might accidentally do something I'm not supposed to.
3. Create my own `Observable` type. This seems to be how the underlying operators work, many of which extend `AbstractObservableWithUpstream`. There is a lot going on here though, and it seems easy to miss something or do something I shouldn't. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to take an approach like this or not. I stepped myself through the mental process, and it seems like it can get hairy pretty quickly.

I'm going to proceed forward with option #2, but thought it worthwhile to ask what the supported method for doing this was in RxJava2 and also find out if there was any documentation or examples for this.

Comment: For #2, I suspect that is the same mechanism that is used to create all of rx' native operators e.g. `buffer`,`window`, etc. So you could go to github and look for the source code for those, to see how they're implemented.

Comment: @Luciano #3 is how all rx native operators are made. As I mentioned above from looking at source code, it gets hairy really quickly. A lot of helper methods are called everywhere. `RxAssembly`, `DisposableHelper`, and they are used in a precise way. It could definitely be done, but I'd just be copying a format. I'd like to make sure I understand what's going on in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing operators is not recommended for beginners and many desired flow patterns can be achieved via existing operators.

Have you looked at RxJava's wiki about [writing operators for 2.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0)? I suggest reading it from top to bottom.

1. using `create()` is possible but most people use it to emit the elements of a `List` with a for-each loop, not recognizing that `Flowable.fromIterable` does that.
2. We kept this extension point although RxJava 2 operators don't use `lift()` themselves. If you want to avoid some boilerplate with option 3. then you may try [this route](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#operator-targeting-lift).
3. This is how RxJava 2 operators are implemented. `AbstractObservableWithUpstream` is a small convenience and not necessary for [external implementors](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#creating-operator-classes).

Answer (score 2):

This may help you. I implement operator RxJava2 to handle APiError. I used lift operator.

See the example.

```
  public final class ApiClient implements ApiClientInterface {
    ...
      @NonNull
      @Override
      public Observable<ActivateResponse> activate(String email, EmailData emailLinkData) {
          return myApiService.activate(email, emailData)
                  .lift(getApiErrorTransformer())
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
      }

      private <T>ApiErrorOperator<T> getApiErrorTransformer() {
          return new ApiErrorOperator<>(gson, networkService);
      }

  }
```

And then you can find custom operator

```
    public final class ApiErrorOperator<T> implements ObservableOperator<T, T> {
        private static final String TAG = "ApiErrorOperator";
        private final Gson gson;
        private final NetworkService networkService;

        public ApiErrorOperator(@NonNull Gson gson, @NonNull NetworkService networkService) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.networkService = networkService;
        }

        @Override
        public Observer<? super T> apply(Observer<? super T> observer) throws Exception {
            return new Observer<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    observer.onSubscribe(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(T value) {
                    observer.onNext(value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError", e);

                if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                        try {
                            HttpException error = (HttpException) e;
                            Response response = error.response();
                            String errorBody = response.errorBody().string();

                            ErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(errorBody.trim(), ErrorResponse.class);
                            ApiException exception = new ApiException(errorResponse, response);

                            observer.onError(exception);
                        } catch (IOException exception) {
                            observer.onError(exception);
                        }

                    } else if (!networkService.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        observer.onError(new NetworkException(ErrorResponse.builder()
                                .setErrorCode("")
                                .setDescription("No Network Connection Error")
                                .build()));
                    } else {
                        observer.onError(e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```